# reading mp3 file for game development

Tags: mp3

I am currently creating a game. My game will use music from an mp3 file that the user sends in in order to make decisions on where to place things, how fast the level moves, etc. I am fairly new at this, I have been reading information about mp3. Currently I have found all the frames in the mp3 file that I am using. I don't really know where to go from here. What I want to do is measure the frequencies of the sound wave of the music at certain times (like every sec) and then based on that frequency, do what I need to for the game. I don't know whether I should decode the mp3, that looks like a lot of work and I don't want to do that if I don't have 2 or if I can just read the bytes in the frame and convert them without decoding anything. I am developing this in c#, using the game engine FlatRedBall. I am not using any libraries. I am also planning on selling this game so I would like to avoid using other people's code if I can avoid it. Please someone help me, I just need a direction to go from here. I know how to parse the header and calculate the framelength, I just don't know the next step in what I want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Convert your music to .ogg format which is free and use free library to play it.

Comment: I think that Will knows about ogg vorbis, so provide a link for c# sdk can be a good Idea

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I was going to post this as a comment but it quickly grew too big. :)*

Writing your own MP3 enconder/decoder is probably going to take a good ammount of effort; effort which would probably be better spent on your game itself. Therefore, is possible, I would be all means try to use an open source library.

That said, most good MP3 libraries are LGPL/GPL licensed. This means you *can* use it in a commercial setting, as long as you **dynamically** link to it. Also the SDL Mixer library, as of version 1.2.12, supports MP3s and is under a more permissive zlib license, but since you mention C# I don't know if stable and up-to-date bindings are available. Also since your project isn't written in SDL to begin with, it might be hard to integrate it.

Also, as @pro_metedor hinted, perhaps using a more open format could help in licensing issues. In general, OGG achieves better compression than MP3, which is a plus for things like download size, bandwidth/resource usage, etc.

Just shop around for a while, and try to be a little flexible. I'm sure you'll find something nice!  :)